# What is the process of requesting a custom image or idea for a site's 404 page?

Tags: support, 404-not-found

I recently had an idea for the 404 page over on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/331/621).  I didn't see any guidance in the help center or FAQ for starting a discussion around or creating a feature request for the 404 page.

How does this process work?  Do moderators have the ability to customize their site's 404 page or is that only available to Stack Exchange employees/community managers?

Comment: I believe that is something only graduated sites get, and comes along with their design. If you have an idea, you'd want to bring it up in the design discussions that pop up around graduation time. I'm not sure if we allow sites to just change it at will when they request it.

Comment: @animuson Ah, that was a follow up, can beta sites even get a custom 404 page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Customization of the 404, captcha, and error pages is part of a site's design, so it's only available for designed sites.

In the past, sites could request custom images via a site meta post tagged "design".  (I don't know if customizing the text was ever supported.)  Apparently, [as of August 2019, these customizations are no longer performed](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4272/congratulations-your-site-design-is-now-live/4282#comment8769_4282).  See [this question asking why it's no longer done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333586/162102).

Comment: The comment you cite only implies to me that they will not pre-supply sites with custom error images as part of their site design; it doesn't imply to me that they will no longer be accepting community-submitted images. (I asked about this in my latest MSE question.) The fact that sites with custom error images continue to have such images, and the fact that Code Golf's error pages were requesting the URLs for (non-existent) custom error images means that the responsive design layout still supports it.

Comment: Also, I don't believe customizing the text was ever supported/done on non-SO sites; Stack Overflow had custom text ("we did, however, find this program"), but that customization was removed when the polyglot was removed and the ability probably isn't even present in the responsive design layout.

Comment: When I said "supported" I meant by people, not by the framework.  It was your question (and a new downvote here) that prompted my edit.  If an answer on your question says sites can have these again, we can always update this answer.