# Custom 404 pages are gone :-(

Tags: support, bug, design, 404-not-found

I just realised [thanks to DavidW](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/58746236#58746236) that all sites have just lost their custom 404 pages, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/abc) for example:

[image]

They're the same across the entire network now, without the fun site customisations. Only [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/abc) still has its funny-hat guys.

Is this a new undesign change, or a temporary accident?

Comment: Error 404: Design not found.

Comment: This comment suggests the change might be intentional: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/359996/can-we-have-a-more-amusing-error-page-for-meta#comment1201351_359996

Comment: eh, yes, that's what you get when an enterprise matures into a high-profile company - a soleless "branded" design everywhere :( Yes, it seems to be intentional - but I wonder why, once again, we didn't get any announcement posts prior to the change going live. P.S. It would be a truly sad day if (when?) we lose the TNG 404 in chat

Comment: @OlegValter The design was always **sole**less, this isn't Nike.

Comment: No way this was an accident.  It's got all the bits and bobs from the previous error pages, just in a single box.  SE.com, though, still has the panda.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Typoed, thanks :) Our precious waffles on MSO are gone too :( Sigh

Comment: @OlegValter No!  Do we need a script?

Comment: @Ollie to get waffles back? I think we do :(

Comment: I genuinely believe part of what brings people in is the feeling of there being a community, as well as some humor in places like the 404 screen. Losing more and more of these (front page on SO and now the 404 pages network-wide) kills the perception of there being a living community involved for people who aren't already a part of the site. Really disappointing that this is the direction we're going in now

Comment: I really liked the pencil stroke graphic of the old 404

Comment: @Zoethe1337Princess TBF, there has been a bit more feeling of humanity and community from the company lately, e.g. [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367713/278659).

Comment: I am probably missing some irony in the comment above, but have to say that: actions speak louder than words, and for now, I see yet another step from the company towards having a network of sites that scream corporate, and that does not give me even a tiny bit more feeling of humanity and community...

Comment: @OlegValter I said "feeling" of humanity and community; of course we've yet to see whether company actions will bear out the fine words from Philippe and others. But engaging directly with the community - asking for priority suggestions, doing community-building exercises, and recognising that different sites have different problems - is surely a good step.

Comment: *"Enterprised to death"* \[Citation needed\]

Comment: EL&U lost a delightful illustration of Alice in Wonderland peeping through a curtain... 

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sorry for the delay. Yesterday got away from me.

I've gone ahead and reverted this change for now. It'll go out in the next deploy. I'm going to instead scope these changes to just Stack Overflow. Stack Exchange will still have its mobile view deleted, but will keep the custom images.

We were looking at 404s on the way to [killing the mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views). A few reasons why we want to simplify them:

1. 404s are meant to be rare. Tonally, we think treating them as jokes can further frustrate already frustrated users.
2. The Stack Exchange network doesn't have dark mode *yet*, but will at some point. Those old custom images will need to be updated to have dark mode alternatives. We don't have the resources to do this right now. This [spot illustration](https://stackoverflow.design/product/resources/spots/) flips colors, and takes custom colors really well.
3. Those custom images aren't retina-ready, meaning they're really blurry on newer, high DPI screens.
4. Those images are also heavier to download than these SVG spot illustrations, though that's not a *huge* concern because, like I said, these pages are rare.
5. Some of those images are cease & desists waiting to happen. We don't own the rights to some, nor do we provide attribution. I have no idea how GitHub gets away with the Star Wars® reference, and I used to work there!

I hear y'all on it feeling like a loss of culture . I'd like for our theming to be more expressive in the future, but we need to balance that and things being future-proof.

We can revisit this when we have a better plan for what to do with those 404 images. We'll be touching a *lot* of stuff on the way to a fully responsive site and we've gotta keep chipping away.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll be honest, this is mostly bad news, but +1 for at least giving people the chance to take pictures before our fun stuff disappears. I hear you about the technical issues (dark mode, not retina-ready, heavier to download), but I have to disagree on your 1st numbered point. So many sites, even those of bigger companies than SE/SO, have funny/cute 404 pages. If it was such a tonal issue, why have so many companies chosen to do it? I'd say it's rather the opposite: if you run into a 404, well, you haven't found the page you wanted, but at least you get a chuckle.

Comment: So, if a community wanted to design their 404 page within some guidelines, similar to how we can submit community ads, would that be an option? There's a lot of creative talent on the network that could probably create clever, properly licensed, dark and light themed pages that captures the character of the site without being too jokey. If a site doesn't want to design something specific, they get the default.

Comment: That's what we need to plan, @ColleenV.

Comment: I really have to agree with @Randal'Thor here. I hit those 404's at least once a day somewhere on the network. With the age of the network, and the amount of deleted posts there are people are bound to run into a 404 every now and then, when being linked from somewhere outside the network. I think there used to be something like: The post you were looking for is deleted, here are similar posts. That would at least be a better page to serve then a 404 when browsing to a deleted post. If that is done, the real use of 404's would indeed become rare.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I don't know whether it's possible, but I kinda wonder whether we could take into account the URL of the page someone was trying to get to and serve different text depending on it - so, for example, if someone's followed a URL to a deleted question, maybe we could display something that recognizes "It looks like the question you found was deleted, if you can't find another similar one, consider asking the question yourself" or something... I don't know all of the reasons people end up on 404s  but it'd be interesting to get some JIT help there.

Comment: @Catija, great minds think alike ;)

Comment: I mean, heck, I wonder if we could even pull the title of the question and a list of the linked questions - so if the question was deleted because it was a downvoted duplicate or something, we could show them questions that might solve their problem. I know that for anon users we generally automatically redirect duplicates to the primary but I don't know whether we do that for deleted duplicates.... hmmm.

Comment: @Catija That would require extra dev time though, to design more customised 404 pages. I'd be happy if they'd just leave the ones we have, they don't need to put effort into making them *better* as long as they don't make them *worse*. (I'm also now getting deja vu because I'm sure I *have* seen this, a 404 page that provides a list of "maybe you meant this instead" links, but it can't be on SE and I'm blanking on where it's from.)

Comment: +1 for the tonal issue -- I find cutesy/'amusing' 404 pages really irritating -- I don't want to see your sense of humour; I want you to serve the page I asked for. (Especially when the page I asked for was linked from elsewhere in your site. Like, perhaps, a deleted question that I don't have permissions to view -- give me some actionable information, not a cute picture.

Comment: If simplicity of execution and consistency across the network is the name of the game,  then at the very least (with a team of developers and designers)  come up with a less boring image than the sketch of a hazard sign. P.S  Last week's MSE  orange theme, that shade was great, super cheerful and knocked my socks off. Loved the SO inspired colour, so much better than a vanilla white 404 page.

Comment: @Catija "*I don't know all of the reasons people end up on 404s*" mostly from browsing daily MSO posts about deleted questions :)

Comment: @Catija That's pretty much what we already do. Check out `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books` in incognito, for example. :) Having said that, the content of these pages hasn't been revisited in many years (and the un-terminated sentences are bugging me), so there's always room for improvement.

Comment: Oh, here's a theoretically better example, even though the options don't actually look relevant: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267546/correct-content-type-http-header-for-json`

Comment: Site designs are already created for Beta sites. Why aren’t 404 pages simply part of the design?

Comment: You say “404s are meant to be rare” but according to some (albeit outdated) [data](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/03/09/anyone-actually-visit-stack-overflows-home-page/?_ga=2.7552247.47992213.1635954947-288748625.1635954947) around 0.52% of page views are on deleted questions (or 1 in 192), or 0.13% (or around 1 in 769) for non-automated traffic. I don’t really think that classifies as rare, but we maybe using different definitions of rare.

Answer (score 23):

> @OlegValter No! Do we need a script? – Ollie 4 hours ago

Yes, yes we do! Custom 404 pages used to be those tiny easter eggs that brought the feeling that the network is actually run by human beings that know how to have a little fun (like Star Trek: The New Generation 404 page in chat).

I guess we can now deprecate the [Waffles meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19480/786798) as well as [Jeff's post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19564/786798) with the iconic image. It is extremely saddening to see that despite all the assurances, the company keeps taking steps in the direction completely opposite to the words spoken.

"Page not found" error page is as known (if not more) as [BSOD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_screen_of_death), and replacing it with a generic one takes out another bit of creativity from the world. Go [to Pixar](https://www.pixar.com/fdgjfh), enter some gobbly-gook in the path, and be greeted with:

[image: pixar 404 page]

Then go [to GitHub](https://github.com/404):

[image: GitHub 404 page]

Then [to Slack](https://slack.com/fjhfghf), and get an animated (!) background:

[image: Slack 404 page]

Even [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/not-found) welcomes you with puppies:

[image: Amazon 404 page]

---

Overall, I feel that the Stack Exchange network lost something important today, but there is still time to salvage at least some of that. I threw together a small userscript that brings back most of the 404 images (see the full list on Stack Apps).

I will continue to expand the roster (more info on [the Stack Apps post](https://stackapps.com/q/9058/78873)) and am open to requests and suggestions for adding more sites and/or images.

[Install](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-404/raw/master/dist/modern/index.user.js) | [Minified](https://github.com/userscripters/bring-back-404/raw/master/dist/modern/index.min.user.js)

[image: Stack Overflow 404]
[image: Meta Stack Overflow 404]
[image: Ask Ubuntu 404]
[image: Super User 404]
[image: English Language Learners 404]
[image: Code Review 404]
[image: UNIX 404]
[image: Sci-Fi 404]
[image: Math 404]
[image: Server Fault 404]
[image: Apple 404]
[image: Cross Validated 404]
[image: Arqade 404]
[image: Mi Yodeya 404]

Comment: I mean... we do still have a custom 404 page, it's just unique to the entire site, just like github's is unique to theirs

Comment: @KevinB we do, but that's not my point - we are supposed to be a network, not a single site (as opposed to GitHub, for example), and all of those sites have communities with their own identity. They lost a bit more of that today... On top of that, even GH, now owned by Microsoft, references an iconic scene from SW with their iconic Octocat. The icon we got is just a warning sign drawn by a competent designer - this is what I call lifeless.

Comment: I don't disagree, i'm just being pedantic, :p I don't necessarily agree with every community needing or deserving it's own design, but surely we could at least get something better than this one

Comment: @KevinB yeah, well, not every had one to begin with :) But there were iconic or at least memorable ones: waffles on MSO, Computer kamasutra on SU, confused search on AskUbuntu, Alice on ELL, etc - and now they are getting replaced with a warning sign... How community-centric of SE - it's not even announced, just dropped

Comment: Also [Discord](https://discord.com/thispagedoesn'texist)

Comment: @Zoethe1337Princess oh, the page's so cute ^^

Comment: OK, I'll give it a shot ;)  But you might have to wait a bit - they take a while.

Comment: @Ollie 6 to 8 weeks was too long to wait, so I made one already ;) Although the search for communities will certainly take a while

Comment: I always appreciate a custom 404 design. Slack's "There's been a glitch" is very misleading for a 404 error though. Just saying...

Comment: @OlegValter 6-8 days, but I'll take that!  Thanks!

Comment: Since we’re mentioning some nice 404 pages: here’s a fox in space on [Patreon](//patreon.com/404page).

Comment: @SebastianSimon nice one, reminds me of my childhood in the 80's playing the [MAD Magazine boardgame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mad_Magazine_Game)

Comment: @SebastianSimon I kind of wish the rocket orbiting the moon was playable on the page :)  On an off-note, if you wait long enough, the fox floats off-screen

Comment: 'Easter egg' 404s are the sort of thing that committed members of the community love and newcomers chuckle at. Once. And then get annoyed by how useless they are.  I like a good joke, but not on the tenth time of hearing it.